# Eclipse RCP e4 Logging

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I amtrying to add logging capabilities to my RCP e4 application.  I found the following Snippet.

```
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Creatable;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Optional;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log.Logger;
@Creatable
public class LoggerWrapper extends Logger {
@Optional
@Inject
private Logger logger;
@Override
public boolean isErrorEnabled() {
            if (logger != null) {
                    return logger.isErrorEnabled();
            }
            return false;
    }
 @Override
public void error(Throwable t, String message) {
              if (logger != null && isErrorEnabled()) {
                    logger.error(t, withPluginInfo(message));
                  }
}
}
```

But I am not sure how to configure/initialize the Logger? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I read `E4Application` correctly it will always initialize the application context to contain a `Logger` which is implemented by `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.WorkbenchLogger`.

You could override this in the `PostContextCreate` method of your Life Cycle class (if you have one).

You can also inject `StatusReporter` which provides simple logging facilities in the Eclipse log (based on `Status` objects).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am implementing an Eclipse (Kepler) 4 application. As far as I know, an Eclipse 4 Application does not use the workbench.  Below is part of my plugin.xml file. Thanks! <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         id="product"
         point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
      <product
            name="com.lanterm.sigma"
            application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
         <property
               name="clearPersistedState"
               value="true">
         </property>

Comment: E4 applications do have a workbench but it is not the same as the old workbench. Everything in my answer is for a pure e4 application.

Comment: Thanks!. I tried to search the web to look for examples/usage of the concepts that you stated above. The only useful thing I found was Lars Vogel tutorial at http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseLogging/article.html. But it was too brief and does use, I think, the approach you stated above. Any other pointers/examples will be highly appreciated. Once more, thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to follow up on my previous comment. I found these links: "Eclipse4/RCP/Lifecycle" at  http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Lifecycle, "Register for the Eclipse 4 application life cycle - Tutorial" at  http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html.

Comment: I found this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1t1qxPBfw0&feature=feedu which describes how add logging (log4j) capabilities to an Eclipse 4 Application.